# Add an image upload box when clicking on the add image box in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

```
<template>
<b-row>
  <b-col md="3" v-for="item in defaultData" :key="item.key">
    <b-form-group>
        <b-form-file
          accept="image/*"
          placeholder="Choose popup invalid image..."
          drop-placeholder="Drop file here..."
          :name=item.keyName
        />
    </b-form-group>
  </b-col>
  <b-col md="2">
    <a-button type="button" class="mr-2" html-type="submit" @click="addimg" ><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a-button>
  </b-col>
</b-row>
</template>
<script>
const defaultData = [
  {
    keyName: product-a2,
    key: 1
  }
]

export default {
  methods: {
    addimg() {
      //
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[image]

I am doing image upload in vuejs.But now I am facing some unresolved problems. I want when I press `@click="addimg"` it will add 1 more photo upload box. Please give me your opinion. Thank you

Comment: You need to make this component and render it with `v-for` for every image.
The "+" button will add 1 more element on the array you are using with `v-for`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use in your methods `this.defaultData.push({})`. Each time you click on your `button` it will push a new `content` to your template.

I've added an `unique ID` as well, because I don't know if your "key" is unique and this will help you out in future coding.

**NOTICE** You can use your b-button inside of the `v-for` but than it will always be pushed too.

Here is how you should change your code:

```
<div v-for="item in defaultData" :key="item.id">
  <!-- ALL OF YOUR DATA IN HERE -->
</div>

<b-button></b-button>
```

```
methods: {
  addimg() {
    this.defaultData.push({
      id: this.id += 1;
    })
  }
}

data() {
  return {
    id: null, 
    defaultData: [   //this is your first "defaultData" in your template 
      { id: 0 } 
    ]
  }
}
```

Hopefully this helps you out! Pls let me know!